# Subclassing Django ModelForms

Tags: django

I want to extend ModelForms with the main purpose of adding fields to the form. I think it is easier to see with an example:

```
# Basic listing
class BasicForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ('category', 'city', 'name', 'address', 
                'slogan', 'phone', 'website', 'email')

class SocialForm(BasicForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = ('facebook','twitter')
```

Would that even work? Or would it just wipe out the other fields from BasicForm in SocialForm?

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a late answer, but I wanted to note that you can subclass the inner `Meta` class like this:

```
class SocialForm(BasicForm):
    class Meta(BasicForm.Meta):
        fields = BasicForm.Meta.fields + ('facebook', 'twitter')
```

That way you don't have to repeat the `model = Business` definition, and any other `Meta` attributes you may add to `BasicForm` will automatically be inherited by `SocialForm`.

For reference, here's the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance) on this approach.