# DjangoForm class meta override

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

i want to override the class Meta in the django forms.

```
class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:

    model = Member
    fields = ["full_name"]
   ..........
   ..........
```

here i want another form class with same functionality of above MemberForm
with an addition field age . how can i achieve this.

```
class EditMemberForm(MemberForm):

   class Meta:
     fields = super.Meta.fields
     fields = fields.append("age")
```

Comment: Subclass the parent's meta class: `class Meta(MemberForm.Meta)`

Comment: @solarissmoke thanks for your answer. can you please point me to a good blog or something like that. please post this as your answer. its working now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subclassing Django ModelForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938521/subclassing-django-modelforms)